# What is wrong with this PhP code of checking NULL

Tags: php

```
static $result = NULL;

if  (!isNull($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```

This is a lazy loading pattern. I initialized the $result to NULL. Then I check if it's NULL. If it is, compute data.

Well the program crash at that line. Also isNull($result) yields null, rather than true or false.

What's the problem?

Comment: next time, please post the error message

Comment: isn't isNull spelt [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)?

Comment: I wonder if it's quicker to find the answer in documentation than posting new question to SO.

Comment: I personally feel these questions can be good for SO. Users new to PHP might search for the same thing and end up here as a result. That in turn increases SO's presence on the web. This is of course just my opinion as I agree more work should of been done by the OP.

Comment: Okay I GOT IT. It's a stupid mistake. I've been trying hard to find the problem you know. I am an experienced PhP programmer and it just misses me. There is no error message. It just crash.

Comment: There is no easy way in zend to know that I am doing this wrong. No warning. Nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no `isNull` function in PHP, it is `is_null`

Answer (score 1):

there is no function called `isNull` in php use `is_null` php function.

`is_null` — **Finds whether the given variable is NULL**, Returns `TRUE` if var is null, `FALSE` otherwise.

```
if(!is_null($var))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if  (! is_null($result))
 {
     echo  $result;  // no return use echo
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `is_null` not `isNull`

```
static $result = NULL;

if  (!is_null($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be

```
static $result = NULL;

if  (!is_null($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
static $result = NULL;

if  ($result!==null)
{
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You used wrong null function for check , its not `isNULL` , it is `is_null`**

```
static $result = NULL;

if  (!is_nul($result))
{
    return $result;
}
```